# Trying to understand scala code in Activator reactive maps examples in Play2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, implicit, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to understand the following piece of code in the [Activator reactive maps example](https://github.com/typesafehub/ReactiveMaps/blob/master/app/actors/ClientConnection.scala#L42-L55). I would appreciate if someone can explain the `( __ \ "event")` and `~` part of code.

```
 object UserPositions {
    implicit def userPositionsFormat: Format[UserPositions] = (
      (__ \ "event").format[String] ~
        (__ \ "positions").format[FeatureCollection[LatLng]]
      ).apply({
      case ("user-positions", positions) => UserPositions(positions)
    }, userPositions => ("user-positions", userPositions.positions))
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is converting a Json object into Scala object and vice versa. `(__ \ "event")` means "event" element of Json object, and `~` means joining the elements into a tuple.

Comment: where is the (__ \ "event" ) and ~ syntax defined ?

Comment: I guess somewhere along these paths:
`import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._`

Comment: I found this link useful. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/ScalaJsonCombinators